# Recycler View call from function breaks

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

How would I go about using the code in the function just as. What is stopping me from calling my recycler view from a function?
This is the error that I'm getting.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.canScrollVertically()' on a null object reference
```

Function that gives the error.

```
void PopulateList(View view)
{

mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

final LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
mLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
//mLayoutManager.isSmoothScrollbarEnabled();
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

mAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(EventsData);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

RecyclerViewAdapter Class

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Context;

import com.squareup.picasso.MemoryPolicy;
import com.squareup.picasso.NetworkPolicy;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import jp.wasabeef.picasso.transformations.CropCircleTransformation;

/**
 * Created by  on 9/23/2015.
 */
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends           RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<EventsListData> EventsData;
Context context;

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    public View view;
    public ViewHolder(View v)
    {
        super(v);
        view = v;
    }
}

public RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<EventsListData> EventsData)
{this.EventsData = EventsData;}



@Override
public RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    //ceate a new view
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.events_list_layout, parent, false);

    //set the view's size, margins, padding and layout paremters;
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    // - get elements from your dataset at this position
    // - replace the contenst of the view with that elements

}

    public void setData(int Maxposition)
{

    int position=0;
    TextView txtDisc = (TextView) vh.view.findViewById(R.id.EventDisc);
    TextView txtDistance = (TextView) vh.view.findViewById(R.id.EventsDistance);
    FrameLayout Frame = (FrameLayout) vh.view.findViewById(R.id.EventsFrame);
    ImageView imgView = (ImageView) vh.view.findViewById(R.id.EventsImageView);

    for (int i = 0 ; i <Maxposition ; i++) {
        Picasso.with(this.context).load("file://" + EventsData.get(position).art_work_uri)
                .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)
                .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
                .centerInside()
                .transform(new CropCircleTransformation())
                        //.resize(200, 200)
                .into(imgView);

        txtDisc.setText(EventsData.get(position).description);
        txtDistance.setText(Float.toString(EventsData.get(position).Distance) + " KM");

        Frame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Log.d("XXX","RecyclerView position =");
            }
        });
    }
    position++;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() { return EventsData.size(); }
}
```

Layouts used with the adapter.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.3">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.30"
        android:id="@+id/Frame">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.98"
            android:id="@+id/EventsFrame">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:paddingRight="15dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:id="@+id/EventDisc"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="random test text" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/EventsBlip"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_weight="0.1"
                        android:src="@drawable/point" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="KM"
                        android:id="@+id/EventsDistance"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_weight="0.9"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.02"
            android:background="#888888">

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/EventsImageView" />
</FrameLayout>
```

LogCat as requested...

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.canScrollVertically()' on a null object reference
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.computeVerticalScrollRange(RecyclerView.java:1545)
        at android.view.View.onDrawScrollBars(View.java:12866)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15154)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.draw(RecyclerView.java:3037)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14082)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14105)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14872)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14077)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14105)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14872)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14077)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14105)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14872)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14077)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14105)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14872)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14077)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14105)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14872)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14077)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14105)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14872)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15151)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2657)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14082)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14105)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:266)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:272)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:311)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2528)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2366)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1997)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1077)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5845)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5274)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)
```

PLEASE NOTE!
I noticed if I comment out everything that has to do with RecyclerView it still happens.So I commented out this in the layout XML and it works.

```
<  android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
 />
```

SO I have added a function to my RecyclerViewAdapter Class but not quite sure if it will work. Because I simply cant actually call it from my Object and I can not figure out why? So I can no really see if this will work. Why cant I call it?

```
public void setData(int Maxposition)
{

    int position=0;
    TextView txtDisc = (TextView) vh.view.findViewById(R.id.EventDisc);
    TextView txtDistance = (TextView) vh.view.findViewById(R.id.EventsDistance);
    FrameLayout Frame = (FrameLayout) vh.view.findViewById(R.id.EventsFrame);
    ImageView imgView = (ImageView) vh.view.findViewById(R.id.EventsImageView);

    for (int i = 0 ; i <Maxposition ; i++) {
        Picasso.with(this.context).load("file://" + EventsData.get(position).art_work_uri)
                .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)
                .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
                .centerInside()
                .transform(new CropCircleTransformation())
                        //.resize(200, 200)
                .into(imgView);

        txtDisc.setText(EventsData.get(position).description);
        txtDistance.setText(Float.toString(EventsData.get(position).Distance) + " KM");

        Frame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Log.d("XXX","RecyclerView position =");
            }
        });
    }
    position++;
}
```

Comment: post your complete code and logcat to be more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you call `PopulateList` too late (or not at all). Make sure it is called as soon as possible after creating view, so if you're using `Activity`, then `PopulateList()` must be called in `onCreate`, if you're using fragment, it must be called in `onCreateView`.

You don't have to set adapter/data immediately, but you **must** set layout manager before `RecyclerView` is showing.

Comment: Ok that makes sense but the problem I face now is the data that is not ready for display yet? In some cases it can take quite a while to get all the data from the sources and then pack it into the Object that is going to be displayed. All the resource gathering is done asynchronously so if I am to add the function to onCreate it will run before everything is good to go.

Comment: Also yesterday I noticed if I comment out everything that has to do with RecyclerView it still happens.So I commented out this in the layout XML and it works. 
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
     />

Comment: You can create `setData` method in your adapter, and update data dynamically. This way you would: set up `RecyclerView` immediately with `LayoutManger`; Set up adapter, and hold it in a field; Once you have data, you call `adapter.setData(yourData)`; In adapter's `setData` method you set list and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`